# Django + Apache with wsgi got "Internal Server Error"

Tags: python, django, apache, mod-wsgi, wsgi

I got "500 Internal Server Error", when I try to connected my Django project to Apache Server.

I try lots of way to setting the configuration file, include some method on stackoverflow. But I still can't solve the problem, can you give me some advance?
Thank you very much!

My django project dir like this:

```
|django
    |--MySite
        |--MySite
            |--wsgi.py
            |--django.wsgi
            |--urls.py
            |--settings.py
        |--Blog
            |--__init__.py
            |--views.py
            |--models.py
```

My setting as below:

> 1.httpd-vhosts.conf:
>
> ```
> <VirtualHost *:8080>
>     ServerName local.Test
>     WSGIScriptAlias / /Users/Hao/django/MySite/MySite/django.wsgi
>     <Directory /Users/Hao/django/MySite/MySite>
>         Options Indexes MultiViews
>         AllowOverride All
>         Require all granted
>         <Files wsgi.py>
>             Require all granted
>         </Files>
>     </Directory>
> </VirtualHost>
> ```
>
> 2.django.wsgi:
>
> ```
> import os, sys
> sys.path.append('/usr/local/django')
> sys.path.append('/Users/Hao/django')
> sys.path.append('/Users/Hao/django/MySite')
>
> os.environ['DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE'] = 'MySite.settings'
>
> import django.core.handlers.wsgi
> application = django.core.handlers.wsgi.WSGIHandler()
> ```
>
> 3.Finally, I open 127.0.0.1:8080 in browser, and I got "500 Internal
>   Server Error".

Thanks.

Comment: was you project running before the apache configuration in the localhost?

Comment: And have you looked in the Apache error log to see what errors are listed in there?

Comment: @Exprator Yes, I can run project use "python manage.py runserver"

Comment: @GrahamDumpleton The error msg is "Target WSGI script '/Users/Hao/django/MySite/MySite/wsgi.py' cannot be loaded as Python module.," But I didn't change anything in this file.

Comment: There should be a Python traceback and exception after that message, or some other message explaining why.

Comment: If you are using Python 2.7 (not 3.x), you are missing ``MySite/MySite/__init__.py`` file if your list of files is correct.

Comment: @GrahamDumpleton Sorry, I miss the line below: "ImportError: No module named django.core.handlers.wsgi"

And "MySite/MySite/__init__.py " is in my project correctly. Bacause file is too many, I not list every file in dir.

Answer (score 0):

you must define wsgi.py

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerName local.Test
        WSGIProcessGroup local.Test
        WSGIPassAuthorization On
        WSGIDaemonProcess local.Test python-home=""#must virtual env path python-path=/Users/Hao/django/
        WSGIScriptAlias / /Users/Hao/django/MySite/MySite/wsgi.py process-group=local.Test

        <Directory /Users/Hao/django/MySite/MySite>
                <Files wsgi.py>
                        Require all granted
                </Files>
        </Directory>

</VirtualHost>
```

your wsgi.py should be like that

```
import os

from django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_application

import sys
sys.path.append('/Users/Hao/django/MySite')
os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "MySite.settings")
application = get_wsgi_application()
```

Comment: Can I use the dir which python actually install for "python-home"?

Comment: did use virtual environment or machine level

Comment: I use "which python" to get the path of python. 
But it still show "Invalid option to WSGI daemon process definition." And the line which got error is "WSGIDaemonProcess local.Test python-home='/Users/Hao/anaconda/bin/python' "

Comment: The result of ``which python`` is not used for ``python-home``, is value of ``sys.prefix`` in running instance. See docs about virtual environment at http://modwsgi.readthedocs.io/en/develop/user-guides/virtual-environments.html

Comment: you can  set python-home=/Users/Hao/anaconda

Comment: anaconda this is virtual env name so that i mention above like that

Comment: If ``/Users/Hao/anaconda`` is actually your Anaconda Python installation and not a virtualenv, you cannot use that. If wanting to use alternate Python distribution, mod_wsgi must be compiled for that Python distribution. You can't point mod_wsgi at a Python installation or virtual environment it wasn't compiled for.

Comment: I create a venv in my project, but I still get the same error msg: "Target WSGI script '/Users/Hao/django/MySite/MySite/django.wsgi' cannot be loaded as Python module." and "ImportError: No module named django.core.handlers.wsgi."
I have make sure the project can run in venv correctly.

Comment: can you share your githup repo

Comment: What is ``sys.prefix`` and ``sys.version`` in command line Python run against your virtual environment? What are the same values under mod_wsgi. See http://modwsgi.readthedocs.io/en/develop/user-guides/checking-your-installation.html#python-installation-in-use for how to to the later.